# jQuery - accordion abrir item individualmente

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

Como configuro o plugin accordion do jquery-ui para que quando eu clicar em algum item ele não feche os outros, por exemplo, quando eu clico ele abre o clicado e fecha os outros mas eu quero que quando eu clicar em algum os que está aberto continua aberto, como faço isso?

**Código até o momento:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        texto 2
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        texto 1
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O que há de errado com a pergunta?, por favor quem deu o downvote me diga como posso melhorar a pergunta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu diria que se não quere fechar as outras seções então você não precisa do accordion...

Em vez de um accordion pode fazer assim, e poupa carregar mais um ficheiro de `.js`

CSS:

```
#accordion div {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('#accordion h3').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k63k5/